# Getting 403 forbidden while accessing jquery.js from /vendor/ in heroku

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I'm able to access **composer** packages locally but in **heroku** i'm getting

**In console**

```
GET https://app.com/vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

**In heroku logs**

```
client denied by server configuration:

/app/vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Upon research i found out that heroku denies access to **vendor** directory.

So how am i supposed to access composer packages?

I've jquery specified as composer dependency

**Getting jquery from vendor**

```
<script src="/vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The app is successfully loaded so no problem in **Procfile** just being denied access to **vendor**

Comment: please provide a list of files to your project and the contents of your Procfile